# Assigning an array inside a while loop causes infinite loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
$pie = array('Apple' => 1, 'Cherry' => 3, 'Pumpkin' => 6);
reset($pie);
while (list($k, $v) = each($pie)) {
    echo "$k => $v\n";
    $desserts[]=$pie;
}
```

If the `$desserts[]=$pie` line is commented out, this code block executes as expected.

Why when it is uncommented does it go into an infinite loop?

I do not understand why that happens.  This is a perfect example of what NOT to do, but I don't understand why the complete array is printed over and over.  I thought just the first slice would be repeated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the manual, it warns you not to do what you're doing.

> **Caution**: Because assigning an array to another variable resets the original arrays pointer, our example above would cause an endless loop had we assigned `$fruit` to another variable inside the loop.

[See documenation for `each()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php).

You can achieve the same results using [array_fill](https://www.php.net/array_fill) if you just wanted to make many copies of `$pie`.

```
 $desserts = array_fill(0,count($pie),$pie);
```

Comment: Yes, this is an example of what NOT to do.  I just couldn't get the behavior.  If the pointer is getting reset, why then wouldn't the output be just "Apple => 1" over and over?

Comment: @Swoop PHP works with arrays in a copy when modified approach. When you use `$desserts[]=$pie;` the values are not actually copied to `$desserts` until something is changed. So `reset` might not happen until PHP sees that `$pie` and `$desserts` are no longer the same, and that could be when `$pie` hits the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this loop by using a `foreach` loop instead of the `while` loop:

```
$pie = array('Apple' => 1, 'Cherry' => 3, 'Pumpkin' => 6);
foreach($pie as $k => $v){
    echo "$k => $v\n";
    $desserts[]=$pie;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pie = array('Apple' => 1, 'Cherry' => 3, 'Pumpkin' => 6);
reset($pie);
while (list($k, $v) = each($pie)) {
    echo "$k => $v\n";
    $desserts[]=$pie;
}
```

Doesn't make that much sense. You're basically duplicating the $pie array for each entry in $pie.

Using foreach would be safer. Would the sample below reflect more closely the intended result perhaps?

```
$pie = array('Apple' => 1, 'Cherry' => 3, 'Pumpkin' => 6);
$desserts = array();
foreach($pie as $fruit => $count){
    $dessert = array(
        'fruit' => $fruit,
        'count' => $count
    );
    $desserts[] = $dessert;
}
```